# Why is in this rust tutorial the string beeing converted to bytes?

Tags: rust

I am reading the rust tutorial and in this [section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html) the tutorial converts a string into a byte array
like so:

```
fn first_word(s: &String) -> usize {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }

    s.len()
}
```

They state that this conversion is because we want to find the first instance of the space character so we need to compare to it. My question is why do we need to convert to bytes? What if instead of converting the string to bytes we convert the byte ' ' into a String and compare to that?

Comment: Instead of searching for an other variable length string, searching for an element, a more basic component, a byte, is a good technical simplification. Notice also that the byte index of the word end is returned. _On the other hand, as String gives UTF-8 bytes, possibly multi-byte sequences, the code above happens to use only a single byte space. Fishy too._ Rewriting the above with `find` seems indeed shorter.

Comment: Is the text in italics a quote from somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I first argumented that byte is a good technical simplification. And then in italics came up with a **counter** argument: that the general case requires multi-byte sequences (say for a non-breaking space U+A0). And concluded with the remark, that simply using `find` would be even more direct.

Answer (score 4):

`String`s in Rust are UTF-8 encoded. You can iterate over `char`s but that will be a bit slower because Unicode code points are variable length, and the `char` type is 4 bytes long so you can't fit as many in a cache line.

A space has the same byte representation regardless of whether you are using ASCII or UTF-8 encoding, so this is an easy optimisation. It's also the same amount of code as iterating over `char`s.

But, probably more importantly, the function in question is returning an *index* for where the character is found. Finding the index by iterating over `char`s would tell you how many unicode code points to skip to get to the that position, but you'd have to iterate again each time you wanted to use the index because each preceding codepoint could be anywhere from 1 to 4 bytes long. An index into bytes is much more straightforward and efficient.

For example, with a byte index:

```
let words = String::from("Hello there");
let index = first_word(&words); // byte index
// just a slice
let first_word = str::from_utf8(&words.as_bytes()[0..index]).unwrap();
```

Indexing Unicode code points:

```
let words = String::from("Hello there");
let index = first_word(&words); // code point index
// having to iterate again, and allocate a new String
let first_word: String = words.chars().take(index).collect();
```

Any method to take a slice here would involve calculating the *byte* position first.